# Magento - how to delete imported csv files

Tags: magento, csv

Could you explain me where the csv files are stored allready imported and how can I delete the old ones? I guess this will not affect the datebase.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete them via ssh.  They are located under the `var/imports` folder.  From the root of your magneto folder execute `rm var/imports/*.csv`

Comment: very pragmatic. When I read this question, I would thought about implementing a observer to do this :)